# WHMCS - Save value of field in Curl Get Result in custom client profile field after provisioning

Tags: curl, post, whmcs

I have a problem I can't resolve that easy!
I'm interfacing WHMCS with a third-party app where on module deployment the system call the API of that application and can generate correctly a user account.

Issue start where I wanna delete that user in case the service get delete and this third party app allow me to send a DELETE request only using the ID of the user and not the email or any other informations attached to it.

The ID is generated by the app and it's part of the Result of the original POST request that get made when the account get created, but I cannot find a way to extract it when the user get created and save it on a "Custom Profile Field" for example of the customer so I can recall it at a later stage if that service need to be terminated.

Any suggestion on to capture that result from the post after it get executed?

Thanks!

Edit:

This is the POST Request

```
function request_CreateAccount(array $params)
{
    try {

      $payload = [
           'email' => $params['clientsdetails']['email'],
           'username' => $params['clientsdetails']['firstname'] . ' ' . $params['clientsdetails']['lastname']

       ];

      $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://xxx.website.com/api/v1/user',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($payload),
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'X-Api-Key: xxxxxxxxxxx',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```

The ID needed to suspend/terminate the item and needed in the other DELETE Request is automatically generated, so in the response of the POST request the ID is published in the result.

I just need to find a way to Capture it and save it in the Array I've used as customer data.

Comment: Is it possible we could see a copy of the original POST with the ID highlighted?  It's hard to make sense of this otherwise.  Obviously you'd need to save the ID from that POST.

Comment: I've edited the post with the code requested! I hope it's more clear now!